# How to put a header in between of two images on the same line (using the <div> blocks)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a webpage for an imaginary pizzeria as practice. I want to insert the header of the webpage in between two images(same) such that the three(image, header, image) elements are in line. But with the code below I am getting a screen like this. How do I get them all on one line?

[image]

```html
<body>
  <div style='float:left'>
    <img src='body.png' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
  </div>
  <div style='font-family:amita; font-size:20px;'>
    <h1 align='center' style='margin-bottom:5px;'>Ralph's Pizzeria</h1>
  </div>
  <div style='float:right'>
    <img src='body.png' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
  </div>
  <hr style='clear:both;' />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution if you want to continue to work with float.
Simply move the 2nd image to before the title.

```html
<body>
  <div style='float:left'>
   <img src='body.png' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
  </div>
  <div style='float:right'> <!-- Just moved this up here -->
   <img src='body.png' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
  </div>
  <div style='font-family:amita; font-size:20px;'>
   <h1 align='center' style='margin-bottom:5px;'>Ralph's Pizzeria</h1>
  </div>
  <hr style='clear:both;'/>
 </body>
```

However, I suggest using flex-box if you don't have to support older browsers.

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest solution I came across for this problem. I will try using the flex-box method you suggested, once I figure out what that is.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.header {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex; 
-webkit-box-pack: justify; 
    -ms-flex-pack: justify; 
        justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div>
        <img src='body.png' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
    </div>
    <div style='font-family:amita; font-size:20px;'>
        <h1 align='center' style='margin-bottom:5px;'>Ralph's Pizzeria</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src='body.png' style='width:100px; height:100px;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added a container div and given it the class `header` and applied the flexbox to it.

Comment: I am fairly new to HTML and this is one of my practice snippets. Can you tell me what the flexbox, WebKit-box, and other stuff mean?

Comment: Flexbox is a modern way of creating layouts. More can be read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). What the CSS snippet really is just: `.header { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }`. The additional CSS with prefixes like `-ms-` and `-webkit-` is nothing additional, but required for the CSS to work in older browsers. Hope this explains things more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I really appreciate your help in explaining what all that meant.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this :

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src='https://lorempixel.com/100/100/'>
  <h1>Ralph's Pizzeria</h1>
  <img src='https://lorempixel.com/100/100/'>
</header>
<hr>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I have added the [float] attribute to make sure that images are on the extreme ends of the page